# Ruby exclude directories and or files in search

Tags: ruby

I am trying to find all files in a directory and all subdirectories, that match a certain file extension, but ignore files which match any elements from an 'ignore' array.

Example:

```
ignore = ['test.conf', 'another.conf']
```

The files 'test.conf' and 'another.conf' should be ignored.

So far I have this:

```
Find.find('./').select { |x|
  x.match('.*\.conf$')  # => only files ending in .conf
}.reject { |x|
  # code to reject any files which match any elements from 'ignore'
}
```

I know I can do something like this:

```
Find.find('./').select { |x|
  x.match('.*\.conf')
}.reject { |x|
  x.match('test.conf|another.conf')
}
```

But, consider the array having a large number of files, and do not want to write out all the files (like above)

Help appreciated.

Comment: The method you want would be more robust if `ignore` could also contain names of directories that you wish to skip.

Comment: that is the next step, but I wanted to get the above working properly first.  Thank you for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 3):

What you should be using is `-`.

```
matches - ignore
```

For you purpose, a better way to get the matches is `Dir.glob`. So the whole code should be

```
Dir.glob("**/*.conf") - ignore
```